# Facebook Ads Expo - Ad was re-loaded too frequently

Tags: react-native, facebook, expo, ads

I am trying to implement Facebook Ads on my Expo app.

I have added the following to my app.json

```
"facebookAppId": "00000000000000",
"facebookDisplayName": "MyAppNameHere"
```

I have then created my placement ID's in the Facebook console and added the ad like this in my app following the guide here..

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook-ads/

```
import * as FacebookAds from "expo-ads-facebook";
FacebookAds.AdSettings.addTestDevice(FacebookAds.AdSettings.currentDeviceHash);

<FacebookAds.BannerAd placementId="PlacementIDHere..." type="standard" onPress={() => console.log("click")} onError={(error) => console.log("error", error)} />
```

I am then getting the following error when I go to the view, does anyone know why this is?  My app is still in review on the Facebook page, could this be it?

```
error SyntheticEvent {
"_dispatchInstances": FiberNode {
    "tag": 5,
    "key": null,
    "type": "ViewManagerAdapter_CTKBannerView",
  },
  "_dispatchListeners": [Function onError],
  "_targetInst": FiberNode {
    "tag": 5,
    "key": null,
    "type": "ViewManagerAdapter_CTKBannerView",
  },
  "bubbles": undefined,
  "cancelable": undefined,
  "currentTarget": 597,
  "defaultPrevented": undefined,
  "dispatchConfig": Object {
    "registrationName": "onAdError",
  },
  "eventPhase": undefined,
  "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
  "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
  "isTrusted": undefined,
  "nativeEvent": Object {
    "message": "Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1002 \"Ad was re-loaded too frequently\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Ad was re-loaded too frequently, FBAdErrorDetailKey={
}}",
    "target": 597,
    "userInfo": Object {
      "FBAdErrorDetailKey": Object {},
      "NSLocalizedDescription": "Ad was re-loaded too frequently",
    },
  },
  "target": 597,
  "timeStamp": 1603004611528,
  "type": undefined,
}
```